# Are all Jem'Hadar implicit killers at birth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the Star Trek: Deep Space Nine episode "The Abandoned", the child Jem'Hadar is essentially programmed from birth to become a killer.

Are all the Jem'Hadar programmed this way, or do they evolve naturally into brutal killers?

Answer (score 6):

The Jem'Hadar are genetically engineered to kill and die for the founders. Their violent tendencies are intentional and bred from birth.

In the episode "[To the Death](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/496.htm)" we learn that the Jem'Hadar are little more than biological weapons, bred in artifical wombs known as "hatcheries", possessed of genetic memories controlled by the changelings and chemically addicted to [Ketracel White](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ketracel-white), without which they become irrationally violent and ultimately die.

> **VIRAK'KARA:** We don't sleep.
>
> **DAX:** How about getting something to eat?
>
> **VIRAK'KARA:** The white is the only thing we need.
>
> **DAX:** Don't sleep, don't eat. What do you do for relaxation?
>
> **VIRAK'KARA:** Relaxation would only make us weak.
>
> **DAX:** You people are no fun at all. Glad I'm not a Jem'Hadar woman.
>
> **VIRAK'KARA:** There are no Jem'Hadar women.
>
> **DAX:** So what do you do? Lay eggs?
>
> **VIRAK'KARA:** Jem'Hadar are bred in birthing chambers. We are able to fight within three days of our emergence.
>
> **DAX:** Lucky you. So let me get this straight. No food, so sleep, no women. No wonder you're so angry. After thirty or forty years of that,
>   I'd be angry too.
>
> **VIRAK'KARA:** No Jem'Hadar has ever lived thirty years [...] Few Jem'Hadar live that long. If we reach twenty we are considered
>   Honoured Elders.

In "[The Abandoned](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/452.htm)", the foundling Jam'Hadar boy is instinctively violent, eventually identifying that

> I now know that **anyone who is not a Jem'Hadar is my enemy**.

Answer (score 5):

Well, according to Memory Alpha,

> Jem'Hadar were engineered to be soldiers and ship crews, and nothing
>   more. Their culture shunned all forms of relaxation and recreation, on
>   the belief that such things made them weak

This would seem to indicate that all Jem'Hadar are programmed from birth to be killers.

Comment: Try to add links where possible.